# Disable button in Android

Tags: android, button

How to disable back button in Android code level?

Once the app is loaded the user should not be allowed to press back button. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: try to google for your question before posting into so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `onBackPressed()` as shown below:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do nothing.
}
```